# SQL query can't use variable in FROM statement

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, so sorry for maybe stupid question.

Table will be from this SQL sandbox: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

There is table of format

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity
1               10248   11          12
2               10248   42          10
3               10248   72          5
4               10249   14          9
5               10249   51          40
```

I want to get products with maximum average quantity.

I can get this using the following query:

```
SELECT avg.ProductID, avg.Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT ProductID, AVG(Quantity) Quantity
  FROM OrderDetails
  GROUP BY ProductID
) avg
WHERE avg.Quantity = (
    SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM (
      SELECT ProductID, AVG(Quantity) Quantity
      FROM OrderDetails
      GROUP BY ProductID
    )
)

ProductID   Quantity
8           70
48          70
```

Here I twice use block

```
  SELECT ProductID, AVG(Quantity) Quantity
  FROM OrderDetails
  GROUP BY ProductID
```

because if I use query with `avg` instead of second block

```
SELECT avg.ProductID, avg.Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT ProductID, AVG(Quantity) Quantity
  FROM OrderDetails
  GROUP BY ProductID
) avg
WHERE avg.Quantity = (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM avg)
```

I get error `could not prepare statement (1 no such table: avg)`

So my question is:

1. Is it a kind of syntaxis mistake and could be simply corrected, or for some reason I can't use variables like that?
2. Is there simplier way to make the query I need?

Comment: Any particular kind of SQL?

Comment: From https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc :
Our Try-SQL Editor uses WebSQL to demonstrate SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Consider Common Table Expressions (CTE) using `WITH` clause which allows you to avoid repeating and re-calculating the aggregate subquery. Most RDBMS's supports CTEs (fully valid in your SQL TryIt linked page).

```
WITH avg AS (
  SELECT ProductID, AVG(Quantity) Quantity
  FROM OrderDetails
  GROUP BY ProductID
)

SELECT avg.ProductID, avg.Quantity
FROM avg
WHERE avg.Quantity = (
    SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM avg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not really a syntax thing, this is rather scope: you try to
   reference an alias where it is not in a parent-child relationship. Only this way they can reference each other. (The identifier there is an alias not a variable - that's a different thing.)
2. A simpler way is to create a temporary set before you run the filter condition - as in a previous answer, with a CTE, or you can try with a temp table. These can be used anywhere because their scope is not within a subquery.